# mount root fs to /target

Tags: linux, install, mount, ext3, crunchbang

I am installing crunchbang linux (#!) to my eeePC and it is unable to start the disk partitioner.  I traced the problem to partman and partman-lvm that states

> No volume groups found.

So I have done some snooping, and I can get around that part of the installer (that just hangs) if I can mount my future root partition to /target and then go from there.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble with the `mount` command.

I want to mount /dev/sda1 to /target.  /dev/sda1 is ext3.

When I try

> mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /target
>   it states: 
>   mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /target/ failed: Invalid argument.

To get a place (/target) I simply did mkdir /target.  Perhaps this is not the proper way to do this?

Gracias =)

Comment: It would be helpful to have the output for **fdisk -l**

Comment: @user4122 fdisk is not normally present at this point, unless explicitly loaded in expert mode  `cat /proc/partitions` might be useful however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the right way. It may be that the device `/dev/sda1` doesn't exist yet. You also probably don't need to specify `-t ext3` since that should be default. I don't expect having it would cause any problem though.